# Use ssh key to encrypt and decrypt a password

Tags: python, ssh-keys

My python-script (Python 2.6, on Debian Linux) asks the user for a password, wich is then saved in the users home directory.

Because i don't want to safe the password as plain text, i want to encrypt it somehow. So i thought that maybe i could use the (private) ssh-key of the user to encrypt and decrypt the password thats saved in the file, so that only one with access to the private ssh key can decrypt the saved password.

Is it a good idea to use the private ssh key for this? How can i use the key to encrypt a string in python?

(btw i don't want to use keyring and stuff like that)

**EDIT**

Okay i understand its a bad idea to use the users ssh key for stuff like that. 
Instead i'm now just using base64 encoding, like described here: 
[How does one encode and decode a string with Python for use in a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875771/how-does-one-encode-and-decode-a-string-with-python-for-use-in-a-url)
of course its not save, when someone reads my python script. But its enough for me, not having to save the password as plain text.

Comment: Hashing != encrypting. A hash function does not need private keys.

Comment: Hashing can include a secret, but it doesn't let you recover the hashed material.

Comment: thanks, changed terminology (i meant just crypting/decrypting)

Comment: Why is it that you need to store a secret (password) anyway?

Comment: the script opens a secured web page, where the user has to uses his credentials. to not bother the user for the password everytime he runs my script, i want that its safed permanently after the user first entered it.

Comment: If you have control over the secured webpage (secured how?), you might even want to store the password hashed and send the hashed password to the web page which can then verify it. That way the password can really not be read by anyone.

Comment: The conventional method to this is to store a hashed copy of the password on your server. When the user logs in, generate and store a session key on the client. The session key can't be used to change the password.

Comment: base64 is no more secure than plaintext

Comment: sh-beta: has the slight advantage of not being immediately readable. This gives a slight security advantage not from prying-eyes, but those who don't want to know your password but may happen to see it.

Comment: Base64 encoding, really?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only thing that's definitely worth doing is storing the file that only the user can read.

Your argument for using the ssh key seems to be something like the following:

1. I need to store a password, so I'll encrypt it
2. If I use the user's ssh key to do the encryption this will prevent someone decrypting the password even if they have the source of my script because only the user can read their ssh key.

If you store the encrypted password in a file only the user can read you get the same benefit as using the ssh key without having to bother with reading the users ssh keys at all.

I agree there's some benefit to not storing the password in plain text to prevent someone logged in as `root` just doing:

```
cat secret-password
```

to get the password but remember it would be easy to find the line in your Python script which said:

```
password = decrypt-password(data)
```

and add the following line:

```
print "The user's password is",password
```

Something like [`os.fchown()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.fchown) would do the trick to protect the file, as would just creating the file with the correct permissions in the first place.

You could [`base64` encode](http://docs.python.org/library/base64.html) the password so it is not plain text, but if we assume an attacker can read and edit your script the only thing which will protect the user is the attacker not being able to read the file containing the encrypted password.

If you're really worried about this, just prompt the user for the password each time they run the script.

Comment: the mechanism doesnt has to be "full secured", i just have a bad feeling to store a password as plain text. Maybe someone gets access to my home directory (e.g. the admins at my workspace), then i want that its not that easy to get the password.

Comment: Firstly see the comment above - do you mean hashing which is a one-way operation or encrypting which is a two way operation?  And secondly if the admins at your workspace can log in as `root` they can read any file they like, including everything in your `.ssh` directory.

Comment: corrected the terminology, i meant crypting. ok so i guess its a bad idea to do it like that. But is there any way to get a "little" more security than just saving it as plain text (and with only the user having the right to access it)

Comment: base64 provides absolutely zero security against anything other than shoulder-surfers. If OS permissions aren't sufficient for the security case, then you need a real encryption or hashing mechanism.

Comment: You are right. However, secure or not (its not "that" important), i'm feeling better that the password is not saved as plain text now.

Answer (score 2):

`Is it a good idea to use the private ssh key for this?`

No:

- The private key could be password protected itself.
- It's poor form to go reading user's secret keys.
- It can be changed without regard to your script.

You also seem to be mixing up your terminology. You've used `encoding`, `decoding` and `hashing` when I'd assume you'd mean `encrypting` and `decrypting`.

As Dave Webb points out, your premise that the private key file is read-only to the user and not itself encrypted. You'd be going from "protected by filesystem user-read-only" to "protected by a different file that is user-read-only".

Comment: ok. is there any other way to get a "little" more security than just saving it as plain text (and with only the user having the right to access it) ?