# Urlencode cyrillic characters in Python

Tags: python, string, urlencode

I need to convert a cyrillic string to its urlencoded version in Windows-1251 encoding. For the following example string:

> Моцарт

The correct result should be:

> %CC%EE%F6%E0%F0%F2

In PHP, I would simply do the following:

```
$request = urlencode(iconv("UTF-8", "windows-1251", "Моцарт"));
echo $request;
```

How to accomplish the same goal in Python?

Comment: What have you tried so far? [`urllib.urlencode`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode)?

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/875771/how-does-one-encode-and-decode-a-string-with-python-for-use-in-a-url)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `decode` and `encode` method on string, then use `urllib.quote`

```
import urllib
print urllib.quote(s.decode('utf8').encode('cp1251'))
```

prints

```
%CC%EE%F6%E0%F0%F2
```

Comment: Why did you use 1251?

Answer (score 4):

In Python 3, use the `quote()` function found in `urllib.request`:

```
from urllib import request

request.quote("Моцарт".encode('cp1251'))

# '%CC%EE%F6%E0%F0%F2'
```